# Where in OpenCart's code does it send invoice emails off?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm trying to disable the firing of the invoice email for certain order statuses but can't find where the `email->send` is that does this.
I've commented out all `email->sends` in  `catalog->model->checkout->order.php` and have cleared the cache but still I get an invoice email through. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emails are sent from file:
catalog/model/checkout/order.php as you are saying.

Let's say the order_status_id of the order you want to send the email is: 7 (usually the default order complete status id)

Find the code:

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
$mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
$mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
$mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

$mail->setTo($order_info['email']);
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
$mail->setText($text);
$mail->send();
```

and wrap it with an if statement like this:

```
if($order_status_id == 7){
    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
    $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
    $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
    $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

    $mail->setTo($order_info['email']);
    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
    $mail->setText($text);
    $mail->send();
}
```

This change will construct and send the email only if the order has status_id = 7. Change this order_status_id to yours.

Important Information:
1) If you are using any opencart extension that changes this code, you need to adjust your code ...
2) If you order_status_id is the default order_status_id of your eshop, then you will never get email. Be careful.

Hope I helped. Cheers.